# Mongodb return objectId as string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.getCollection('User').find({
    "userId" : ObjectId("5a141ac4048378xb52c3e5a9"),
        "userRole" : "ADMIN",
        "Id" : "1234567890"})

    result:
    {
        "userId" : ObjectId("5a141ac4048378xb52c3e5a9"),
        "userRole" : "ADMIN",
        "Id" : "1234567890"
    }

    Expecting output:
    {
        "userId" : "5a141ac4048378xb52c3e5a9",
        "userRole" : "ADMIN",
        "Id" : "1234567890"
    }
```

I am very new to mongodb i nedded to return objectId as String ,i neeed some suggestion to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done simply using the below approach

```
db.User.find({"userId": objectId("5a141ac4048378ab52c3e5a9")}).map(
      function(doc) { 
         return { "userId": doc.userId.str}
      });
```

Please see [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-constructor/) for more methods

Comment: myDocument._id.str

Answer (score 0):

You can try use a [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)
But ObjectId isn't strings, it's just numbers, why you want present it as string?

Comment: Aggregation is not needed here, it can be done using simple find query